# Member function with rvalue ref parameter not detected by has_member trait

Tags: c++, c++11

As the title says, i have a member function with a rvalue reference parameter that I want to detect using a has_member trait. If the function is templated, has_member is false, even if i don't use that template parameter.

I think the code will better clarify my issue:

```
class A
{
public:
    void foo(int&&){}
};

HAS_MEMBER(foo); //macro that creates the struct has_member_foo<TYPE, SIGNATURE>

has_member_foo<A, void (A::*)(int&&) >::value == true


class A
{
public:
    template <typename T> //if the function is templated, it's not detected.
    void foo(int&&){}
};

has_member_foo<A, void (A::*)(int&&) >::value == false
```

*Note that I've tested with multiple implementations of has_member trait. Also, if i use normal references, everything works as expected.*

**How should I test for this function's existence? Is the signature wrong or I'm missing something else?**

Also, for Visual Studio 2015, if the parameter is an universal ref, it works, but for Visual Studio 2012, it doesn't.

```
class A
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    void foo(T&&){}
};

has_member_foo<A,void (A::*)(int&&)>::value //true for vs2015, false for vs2012
has_member_foo<A,void (A::*)(int&)>::value //true for vs2015, false for vs2012
has_member_foo<A,void (A::*)(const int&)>::value //true for vs2015, false for vs2012
```

**One of the implementations tried for has_member is this:** https://github.com/snaewe/typeswitch/blob/master/has_member.hpp

Comment: Indeed, for your second class A, `void A::foo(int&&)` doesn't exist, but `void A::foo<std::string>(int&&)` does.

Comment: And is there a way to express that in the function's signature? Something like `has_member_foo<A,void (A::*)<std::string>(int&&)>::value`? Or i must modify has_member?

Comment: For the last part, code from `has_member_foo` should be required.

Comment: My (old) macro does [that](https://ideone.com/k8QRd5) if it helps. We will have [experimental/is_detected](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected).

Comment: This works, Thank you! I couldn't do this with the previous versions of has_member that I've tried because  they appended the function name to the generated class name, so it couldn't be something like `T::template foo<int>`.